# How to set default product group price in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product, price, group-price

We have 3 customer group.
When we create a new product at that time we want all 3 groups are selected and it's price set default 0(zero).
Anyone help me to set this type of functionality.
Find attach image for more clear my requirement.[image]

Comment: How you will create your product? Manual OR CSV?

Comment: @Ravi we create it Manually

Comment: I m suggesting you to create CSV it will easy to meet your requirement.

Comment: @Ravi  I am also know this thing but requirement is different.

Comment: Let me check and update you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have Added another answer. Might First answer will help someone.

So now here you have to override:

> /app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/price/group.phtml

You should update your code from the line number: 55 and use below code with a condition I have added.

```
    <?php if(empty($this->getValues())): ?>
    <tbody id="group_price_container">
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none">
            <select class=" input-text required-entry" name="product[group_price][0][website_id]" id="group_price_row_0_website">
                <option value="0">All Websites [USD]</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class=" input-text custgroup required-entry" name="product[group_price][0][cust_group]" id="group_price_row_0_cust_group">
                <option value="0">NOT LOGGED IN</option>
                <option value="1" selected>General</option>
                <option value="2">Wholesale</option>
                <option value="3">Retailer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class=" input-text required-entry validate-zero-or-greater" type="text" name="product[group_price][0][price]" value="0.00" id="group_price_row_0_price"></td>
        <td class="last"><input type="hidden" name="product[group_price][0][delete]" class="delete" value="" id="group_price_row_0_delete"><button title="Delete Group Price" type="button" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" id="group_price_row_0_delete_button" onclick="return groupPriceControl.deleteItem(event);"><span>Delete</span></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none">
            <select class=" input-text required-entry" name="product[group_price][1][website_id]" id="group_price_row_1_website">
                <option value="0">All Websites [USD]</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class=" input-text custgroup required-entry" name="product[group_price][1][cust_group]" id="group_price_row_1_cust_group">
                <option value="0">NOT LOGGED IN</option>
                <option value="1">General</option>
                <option value="2" selected>Wholesale</option>
                <option value="3">Retailer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class=" input-text required-entry validate-zero-or-greater" type="text" name="product[group_price][1][price]" value="0.00" id="group_price_row_1_price"></td>
        <td class="last"><input type="hidden" name="product[group_price][1][delete]" class="delete" value="" id="group_price_row_1_delete"><button title="Delete Group Price" type="button" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" id="group_price_row_1_delete_button" onclick="return groupPriceControl.deleteItem(event);"><span>Delete</span></button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="display:none">
            <select class=" input-text required-entry" name="product[group_price][2][website_id]" id="group_price_row_2_website">
                <option value="0">All Websites [USD]</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class=" input-text custgroup required-entry" name="product[group_price][2][cust_group]" id="group_price_row_2_cust_group">
                <option value="0">NOT LOGGED IN</option>
                <option value="1">General</option>
                <option value="2">Wholesale</option>
                <option value="3" selected>Retailer</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td><input class=" input-text required-entry validate-zero-or-greater" type="text" name="product[group_price][2][price]" value="0.00" id="group_price_row_2_price"></td>
        <td class="last"><input type="hidden" name="product[group_price][2][delete]" class="delete" value="" id="group_price_row_2_delete"><button title="Delete Group Price" type="button" class="scalable delete icon-btn delete-product-option" id="group_price_row_2_delete_button" onclick="return groupPriceControl.deleteItem(event);"><span>Delete</span></button></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
<?php else: ?>
    <tbody id="<?php echo $_htmlId; ?>_container"></tbody>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Code look not well but it is the only solution.

Comment: Yes it's working as per my requirement. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for mark as a right answer. :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this solution.

For this you have to override below file

> /app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php

Updated code here:

```
/**
 * Save product action
 */
public function saveAction()
{
    $storeId        = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store');
    $redirectBack   = $this->getRequest()->getParam('back', false);
    $productId      = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
    $isEdit         = (int)($this->getRequest()->getParam('id') != null);

    $data = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
    if ($data) {
        $this->_filterStockData($data['product']['stock_data']);

        $product = $this->_initProductSave();

        try {
            $defaltSetGroupPrice = array(

                array('website_id' => 0, 'cust_group' => 1, 'price' => 0, 'delete' => ''),
                array('website_id' => 0, 'cust_group' => 2, 'price' => 0, 'delete' => ''),
                array('website_id' => 0, 'cust_group' => 3, 'price' => 0, 'delete' => ''),
            );
            $product->setData('group_price', $defaltSetGroupPrice);
            $product->save();
            $productId = $product->getId();

            if (isset($data['copy_to_stores'])) {
                $this->_copyAttributesBetweenStores($data['copy_to_stores'], $product);
            }

            $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('The product has been saved.'));
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage())
                ->setProductData($data);
            $redirectBack = true;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
            $redirectBack = true;
        }
    }

    if ($redirectBack) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array(
            'id'    => $productId,
            '_current'=>true
        ));
    } elseif($this->getRequest()->getParam('popup')) {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/created', array(
            '_current'   => true,
            'id'         => $productId,
            'edit'       => $isEdit
        ));
    } else {
        $this->_redirect('*/*/', array('store'=>$storeId));
    }
}
```

Here in this variable $defaltSetGroupPrice Set your cust_group ID and check.

Comment: Sorry for this code. We want when we create new product at that time this option default selected. For example; when we click on Add new product  button at that time product visibility by default show 'Catalog, Search'. Please update code for this functionality.

Comment: Okay, Once you click on Add Product then you have to select a product type. On which product type you want this?

Comment: Simple product.